# Mojave Update: How do you fix these errors?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, cocoapods

Hi I just updated my iMac with the new Mojave and am now getting these errors on my project. I have spent some time searching for solutions and have yet to find one. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. 
[image: Image With Errors Here]

**1.** error: /Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App01-dvsqcwpxxkpcbwhkdrzcmteyzypa/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire/Alamofire.framework: No such file or directory

**2.** error: /Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App01-dvsqcwpxxkpcbwsadfssdteyzypa/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework: No such file or directory

**3.** Multiple commands produce '/Users/MyUsername/Desktop/App01/DerivedData/App01/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App01.app/Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework':

**4.** Multiple commands produce '/Users/MyUsername/Desktop/App01/DerivedData/App01/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App01.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework':

**SOLUTION:** [Project_Name] > Build Phases > Embed Frameworks and remove the duplications there.

Comment: Please don't post screenshot of your errors. Instead copy the error and post as text.

Comment: have you tried deleting your derived data and building again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4-and-later)

Answer (score -1):

First, Command-Option-Shift-K to clean out the build folder and build again. If you still got this error, go to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and remove all the files.

More detail:
[How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4-and-later)